# Is it 10 lessons class, or 10 lesson classes?

Tags: grammar, plural-forms

When there are 2 nouns in the sentence continuously. It's hard to determine where to put the 's'. Is there a standard rule anyone can share with us. So that we can be sure next time.

Comment: I wouldn't use either. What exactly are you trying to say?

Answer (score 2):

We *don't* normally pluralize the "counted" noun (***lesson***, here) when a ***count + noun*** element is being used *adjectivally* before the "main" noun (***class***, here).

Hence it's ***a ten lesson class, a ten foot pole, a three cheese pizza,...***

I don't want to get bogged down in hyphenation. If you've seen ***ten-foot poles*** hyphenated before, by all means copy what you've seen. But when in doubt, just don't use hyphens - they're rarely *necessary*.

---

Whether to use ***class*** or ***classes*** simply depends on whether you're referring to one such class, or several.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, the proper hyphenation (and more correct grammar) would be "ten-lesson class". When using a compound adjective, the two adjectives are operating as one singular idea and don't make sense on their own, so you hyphenate them. A "ten class" doesn't make sense, nor does a "lesson class", so it's a "ten-lesson class". On the other hand, an "online night class" is not hyphenated, because an "online class" and a "night class" both make perfect sense. And finally, something like a "very hard class" would also not be hyphenated, because "very" is an adverb, not an adjective.

Comment: In case anyone's interested, I ***don't agree*** that including a hyphen is "correct grammar". That's a ***stylistic choice***, which is more likely to be taken with some collocations than with others. And *as a general principle*, I think that option is chosen less often as time goes by.

Comment: On further review, I think you're right. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/hyphen-rules-open-closed-compound-words) says that it's often down to both individual words and the author's preference. I think I was letting my own style leech in. I stand by the logic of whether a hyphen makes sense or not, but concede that it's not necessarily more correct to have one overall.

Comment: I just searched Google Books for "a ten lesson course" (GB doesn't index punctuation marks, so both orthograhies match that search string). I only looked at the first page of results, but 4 were hyphenated, as against 6 that weren't. It would be interesting to see if there's been any significant change over time, but I don't know how to do that with hyphenated text.